# When does $ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \, (\underbrace{f \circ \dots \circ f}_{n}) (\xi)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

$\newcommand{\coloneqq}{\colon\!=}$
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a_0, \dots, a_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_k \neq 0$. Let 
$$\begin{align*}
f: \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus \{0\} &\to \mathbb{R} \\
\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\smallsetminus \{0\} \quad x&\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^{k} \frac{a_i}{x^i}
\end{align*}$$

Let's define $f^{\left[n\right]}$ recursively 
$$ \begin{align*}
f^{\left[1\right]} &\coloneqq f \\
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\smallsetminus \{0\} \quad f^{\left[n+1\right]} &\coloneqq f \circ f^{\left[n\right]} 
\end{align*}$$
Let $\xi \in \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{0\}$ such that $f(\xi)\neq 0$. What conditions on $a_0, \dots, a_k$ and $\xi$ are sufficient for the existence of the following limit?
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \, f^{\left[n\right]} (\xi)$$

---

I have only solved the case $k=1$ so far. If I am not mistaken, the limit exists when $P_2(x):=x^2-a_0x-a_1$ has real roots and $a_0 \neq 0$. Moreover, if the limit exists, then: if $\xi$ is a root of $P_2(x)$, then the limit converges to it, otherwise it is the value of the continued fraction $\left[ \overline{a_0,\frac{a_0}{a_1}} \right]$, which is a root of $P_2(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_k(x)=a_0+a_1\,x+\dots+a_k\,x^k$. If $f^{[n]}(\xi)$ converges, the limit will be a solution of the equation
$$
p_k\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)=x.
$$
This is a polynomial equation of degree $k+1$; if $a_k>0$, then there is at least a positive solution. Given a real solution  $\eta$, let
$$
m_\eta=\frac{d}{dx}\,p_k\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)\Bigr|_{x=\eta}=-\frac{1}{\eta^2}\,\,p'_k\Bigl(\frac1\eta\Bigr).
$$
If $|m_\eta|<1$, then for $\xi$ close enough to $\eta$ the sequence $f^{[n]}(\xi)$ will converge to $\eta$.

Without further knowledge of the coefficients $a_i$, I do not think that nothing more specific can be said.

Comment: Even though this is not what I expected, thank you for your answer!